# How to open and edit a Settings.settings file?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to open and edit a Settings.settings file that a program uses. I need to edit a lot of settings and if I use the programs interface it would take me hours. So, I thought I could open up its .settings file and change it easier in there.

I have searched everywhere for an answer on how to open and edit this file, with no luck. I fond that it is a `C#` settings file, and Visual Basics can open it. I believe it has something to do with the `.NET framework` also.

I have VS express 2013 tried to find a way to open it, but for some reason I can not open it. I created a `C#` project in VS express, is there a way that I can import and edit this file form there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open and edit it from VS.
On solution Explorer go to:

```
Your Project->Properties->Settings.settings (right click-> Open)
```

Have in mind, that if your project does not connect any settings file, then none will displayed on Solution Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have the file in Solution Explorer, when I open it I get an error "There is no editor available for" file and then "Make sure the application for the file type (.settings) is installed. I thought VS was the editor? Again thanks for your help